# How to open keyboard in surface mode

Tags: c#, keyboard, pixelsense

Currently, I'm developing an application for de sur40 with PixelSense 2.0.

Now the problem is, when I'm in debug mode, I can let appear the Windows 7 onscreen keyboard, but when I enter the SurfaceMode the white build in keyboard doesn't appear when I focus on a text block.

So my question is: How can I make that white build in keyboard appear in the SurfaceMode?

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me to let the keyboard appear in SurfaceMode.The example at the bottom is very helpfull.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.surfacekeyboard.aspx

Another example which is slightly different. The example works, but in my case it doesn't
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.surfacetextbox.keyboardpositioning.aspx